Performance vs flexibility in a Unity Node Graph Editor Tool
I'm developing a node-based editor tool in Unity with pure UIToolkit (no existing graph frameworks). The premise is that the graph needs to be scene-based, so it's a Monobehaviour, rather than a ScriptableObject, as most other graph systems do.
Inside each node, there can be PropertyFields that potentially draw a custom property UI.
I've implemented two approaches, both with their drawbacks and benefits.
1. In memory ScriptableObjects for the Graph and the Nodes, like so:
    public class GraphComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeReference]
        [HideInInspector]
        public GraphData graphData;

        ...

    public class GraphData : ScriptableObject
    {
        [HideInInspector] public string GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        [HideInInspector]
        [SerializeReference]
        public List<NodeData> nodes = new();

        ...

    public abstract class NodeData : ScriptableObject
    {
        [NodeHideVariable]
        public string guid = "";

        [SerializeReference]
        public GraphData graphData;

        ...

Then of course there are lots of ViualElement derived classed that define how nodes, edges etc. look.
In the NodeElement class there are methods to build a nodes VisualElement hierarchy, the most important one being BuildValues() iterating over the fields and creating PropertyFields, roughly like so:
        public void BuildValues()
        {
            var _editor = Editor.CreateEditor(nodeData);
            var sp = _editor.serializedObject.GetIterator();

            sp.NextVisible(true);
            while (sp.NextVisible(false))
            {
                System.Type t = sp.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
                
                FieldInfo f = null;
                f = t.GetField(sp.propertyPath);
                if (f != null)
                {
                    var _hideAttribute = f.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(NodeHideVariable), true);
                    if (_hideAttribute == null)
                    {
                        var _property = new PropertyField();
                        _property.BindProperty(sp);

                        valuesContent.Add(_property);
                    }
                }
            }
            _fromNodeInspector = false;
            
            _editor.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

This approach runs extremely efficient and easily handles graphs with 200 nodes and more, with a butter smooth framerate in the editor. Absolute joy to work with. It serialized the in-memory ScriptableObjects to the Unity scene as expected.
The catch: It obviously doesn't work if you want to make a GraphComponent a prefab, by dragging it into the Project panel.
The graphData will contain no nodes whatsoever, as references to ScriptableObjects are not serialized to prefabs in Unity.
So I'd have to dive deeply into a rabbithole of generating ScriptableObject subassets for each node and somehow manually resolving the internal references to scene objects, that are within the Prefab hierarchy (if that's even possible).
So I tried a second approach:
2. Using System.Serializable classes for GraphData and NodeData, like so:
GraphComponent stays unchanged.
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GraphData
    {
        [HideInInspector]
        [SerializeReference]
        public MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour; // store to which GraphComponent we are attached
        
        [HideInInspector] public string GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        
        [HideInInspector]
        [SerializeReference]
        public List<NodeData> nodes = new();
        
        ...

    [System.Serializable]
    public abstract class NodeData
    {
        [NodeHideVariable]
        public string guid = "";
        
        [SerializeReference]
        public GraphData graphData;
        
        ...

The new BuildValues() also iterates over the GraphComponent as a SerializedObject and binds PorpertyFields to its SerializedProperties down the serialization chain:
        public void BuildValues() {
            SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(graphData.monoBehaviour);
            serializedObject.Update();

            // Find GraphData property
            SerializedProperty graphDataProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("graphData");

            // Find nodes list
            SerializedProperty nodesProperty = graphDataProperty.FindPropertyRelative("nodes");

            // Find index of nodeData in nodes list by comparing GUIDs
            int nodeIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesProperty.arraySize; i++)
            {
                SerializedProperty nodeProperty = nodesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                SerializedProperty guidProperty = nodeProperty.FindPropertyRelative("guid");
                if (guidProperty != null && guidProperty.stringValue == nodeData.guid)
                {
                    nodeIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (nodeIndex == -1)
            {
                Debug.LogError("NodeData not found in GraphData nodes list.");
                return;
            }
            // Get SerializedProperty for nodeData
            SerializedProperty nodeDataProperty = nodesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(nodeIndex);

            // Clear existing content
            valuesContent.Clear();

            // Iterate over nodeData fields
            SerializedProperty iterator = nodeDataProperty.Copy();
            SerializedProperty endProperty = nodeDataProperty.GetEndProperty();

            // Move into the first child of nodeDataProperty
            if (iterator.Next(true))
            {
                int startingDepth = iterator.depth; // Record the starting depth

                do
                {
                    // Stop if we've reached the end property or exited the current depth
                    if (SerializedProperty.EqualContents(iterator, endProperty) || iterator.depth != startingDepth)
                        break;
                    
                    // Get the corresponding FieldInfo
                    FieldInfo fieldInfo = nodeData.GetType().GetField(iterator.name,
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

                    if (fieldInfo == null) continue;

                    // Create PropertyField
                    PropertyField propertyField = new PropertyField(iterator.Copy());
                    propertyField.Bind(serializedObject);
                    valuesContent.Add(propertyField);
                } while (iterator.NextVisible(false));
            }

            // Apply changes when needed
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

This approach works perfectly and naturally with Prefabs, but as soon as you have more than 30-35 nodes it lags like crazy and makes the graph tool unusable.
From Profiler runs I found that because the PropertyFields are bound to the higher level Monobehaviour, Unity will serialize the whole structure with every little change. So, e.g., when ou move a single node, all other nodes are updated and rendered.
I tried to be smart and wrap the NodeData Objects into a NodeDataWrapper class (derived from ScriptableObject) that only holds a reference to the same NodeData, and bind the PropertyFields to those ScriptableObject wrappers instead, but no difference in performance.
So the question is: can this latter approach be made efficient in rendering, while using System.Serializable classes to maintain Prefab workflow compatibility?
Update: I also tried a custom property drawer for my NodeData objects so Unity would auto-bind to the properties but the performance is still laggy and no different than before.

Drawback of a serializable class is that there is no connection between the same instances .. so if you reference the same instance in two places it will be serialized as independent instances so after deserialization the connection is lost .. also for anything that is not a UnityObject reference you serialize the entire hierarchy (up to a certain depth limit) which is quite undesirable in your use case

Unity themselves often use the Graphs Tool Foundation Framework which is ScriptableObject based but then works with nodes based on unique IDs in order to handle multiple references to the same node .. you use this e.g. if you use the Shader Graph or Bolt

Im my case it's okay to have one graph per Monobehaviour and not two of them reference the same GraphData object. I see no alternative to serialize the entire hierarchy of graph and all its nodes. Thats also done in the ScriptableObject case.
The GTF is unfortunately not usable at the moment and the experimental GraphView is deprecated and won't come out of the experimental state.

Instead of your GraphComponent what speaks against having this as a root ScriptableObject so all sub ScriptableObject are stored within that root? This way you can reuse it like a prefab, create copies etc ..

GTF is usable .. it's just inconvenient and you have to build a lot of assembly bridges and refactor internal code to adopt it to your use case ^^ but it's quite a good starting point actually

The GraphComponent cannot be a ScriptableObject in my case, as the nodes and its fields need to contain references to scene objects (GameObjects, Monobehaviours). So it must be attached to the scene in form of a Monobehaviour.

I suppose in that case anyway the "prefab ability" is kinda not really required as it would fall under the same issue of loosing scene references anyway right?

Prefabs only lose external scene refs. References to scene objects that lie within the prefab hierarchy are well preserved when creating a prefab from a GameObject.

Well fair point ^^ I know of graph tools that solved that .. but tbh right now I don't remember how. I would have to dig it up again .. I worked on a GTF based graph that was similar to Bolt which also has its way to store and resolve scene and prefab internal references

Would be awesome if you could dig out that solution of yours! You could post it as a solution to this question.
